# How to make Node.js and Glassfish server listen to the same port?

Tags: node.js, glassfish, port, stripe-payments

I am running my web application using Glassfish server which is running on port 8080. For the same web application, I am trying to integrate Stripe API using node.js. Rest of my web application runs on localhost:8080.

So how do I listen to the same 8080 port through node.js and also glassfish for so that my web application is integrated with Stripe node.js.

Should I use web sockets?

HTML page:

```
    <body>        

        <form id="form" action="/acctCreated" method="POST">
        <label>Card #: <input type="text" size="16" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card number" /></label>
        <label>Expiry month: <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="MM" /></label>
        <label>year: <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="YY" /></label>
        <label>CVC: <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="CVC" /></label>

        <button type="submit">Pay</button>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_mHCVXXlu5il6pgbQCQzmKY2S');

        var $form = $('#form');
        $form.on('submit', function() {
            // First submit the card information to Stripe to get back a token
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response) {
                var token = response.id;

                // Save the token into a hidden input field
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

                // Now submit the form to our server so it can make the charge against the token
                $form.get(0).submit();
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
    </body>
```

index.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_bpfjQsY5iK7ZI7W5tJMKpPli');
    var http = require('http');

    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

      app.post('/acctCreated', function(req, res) { 
        console.log('Inside charge');
        //var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
        var stripeToken = req.body.id;
        var amount = 1000;

        console.log('Calculating charge');
        stripe.charges.create({
            card: stripeToken,
            currency: 'usd', 
            amount: amount
        },
        function(err, charge) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, err);
                //res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                res.send(204);
                //res.status(204).send(charge);
            }
        });

          var path = "http://localhost:8080/TropoHotelReserv/faces/roomsBooked.xhtml"  ;
          console.log("Get PathName " + path);
          res.writeHead(302, {'Location': path});
          res.end();

        console.log('Complete');
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is the Stripe API piece called from the user's browser or from the business logic inside your servlets in Glassfish?

Comment: Its called from the browser.

Comment: Websockets are for low-level message-oriented communications.  It will likely complicate this without giving you any value.  If you had to update a live order feed as other requests come in from other clients it would be a fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly.  You need a load balancer/router in front listening on 8080.

Run Glassfish on port 8081 and Node.js on 8082, then use a load balancer (ex. stud, haproxy, apache httpd, or varnish) in front and set up localhost:8081 and localhost:8082 as backends for the corresponding URL paths.

Here's an example of using HAProxy that way

> You can segregate requests based on URL and load balance with a single HAProxy server.
>   Your configuration will have something like this:
>
> ```
> frontend http
> acl app1 path_end -i /app1/123 #matches path ending with "/app/123"
> acl app2 path_end -i /app2/123 
> acl app3 path_end -i /app3/123 
>
>
> use_backend srvs_app1    if app1
> use_backend srvs_app2    if app2
> use_backend srvs_app3    if app3
>
> backend srvs_app1 #backend that lists your servers. Use a balancing algorithm as per your need.
>    balance roundrobin 
>    server host1 REGION1_HOST_FOR_APP1:PORT 
>    server host2 REGION2_HOST_FOR_APP1:PORT
>
> backend srvs_app2
>    balance roundrobin
>    server host1 REGION1_HOST_FOR_APP2:PORT 
>    server host2 REGION2_HOST_FOR_APP2:PORT
>
> backend srvs_app3
>    balance roundrobin
>    server host1 REGION1_HOST_FOR_APP3:PORT 
>    server host2 REGION2_HOST_FOR_APP3:PORT
> ```
>
> More information can be found on the [homepage][1].
>
> [1]: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20640578

On Windows you could use mod_proxy in Apache httpd:

```
ProxyPass /nodejspath http://localhost:8081/nodejspath
ProxyPass /glassfishpath http://localhost:8081/glassfishpath
```

More info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Isnt HAProxy just for Linux. I run on WIndows

Comment: @Shilpa did this work for you? If so, can you accept it as the correct answer?