# HAProxy - URL Based routing with load balancing - using listen and use-server

Tags: configuration, haproxy, round-robin

I need to configure HAProxy to forward requests of different paths to different backends, and some of the backends need to be load-balanced. So I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606544/haproxy-url-based-routing-with-load-balancing), and the solution provided there does work, but due to our conventions, I need to use `listen` and `use-server` instead of `frontend` and `use_backend`.

So right now I have something like this:

```
listen poq [url]:[port]
    acl has_cool_url path_beg -i /cool
    use-server cool if has_cool_url
    server cool [ip]:[port] check
    server default [ip]:[port] check
```

And I cannot use this:

```
listen poq [url]:[port]
    acl has_cool_url path_beg -i /cool
    use_backend cool if has_cool_url
    use_backend notcool if !has_cool_url

backend cool
    balance roundrobin
    server first [ip]:[port] check
    server second [ip]:[port] check

backend notcool
    server third [ip]:[port] check
```

Because our conventions tell us to define everything within the `listen` block.

So my question is: is there anything like this:

```
listen poq [url]:[port]
    acl has_cool_url path_beg -i /cool
    use-server {first, second} if has_cool_url
    server first [ip]:[port] check
    server second [ip]:[port] check
    server default [ip]:[port] check
```

Where `first` and `second` are load-balanced using round robin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conventions are arbitrary and are limiting your functionality.  A `listen` block is functionally similar to a single `frontend` and a `backend` block with the same name, and an implicit `default_backend` pointing from frontend to backend.  `listen` blocks are intended to be used for simple configurations.

The point of a backend is that all servers in the back-end provide the same service.  `use-server` allows you to select exactly one server.

The *only* thing you can do with `listen` is balance a single default set of servers, plus one or more individual servers, individually addressable using condition matches, but they can't be balanced.

```
listen poq [url]:[port]
    acl has_warm_url path_beg -i /warm
    use-server warm-server if has_warm_url
    acl has_hot_url path_beg -i /hot
    use-server hot-server if has_hot_url
    server warm-server [ip]:[port] check weight 0
    server hot-server [ip]:[port] check weight 0
    server default1 [ip]:[port] check
    server default2 [ip]:[port] check
```

In this configuration, /warm goes to warm-server, /hot goes to hot-server.  These two servers are weighted 0 to prevent them from handling any other requests.

Everything else is balanced between default1 and default2.

This is all the flexibility you have with `listen` because HAProxy only does one set of balancing per backend, and, as noted above, a `listen` section is an implicit combination of the functionality of a matched set of `frontend` and `backend`.

Comment: The solution you offered works perfectly well for my purpose, thanks. I agree that the conventions are arbitrary!