# How to have a Wordpress site on foo.example, and another Wordpress site on foo.example/bar?

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I have a legacy WordPress blog that runs only in PHP 5.2 (lot's of incompatibilities in later versions), and I am developing a new Wordpress blog that should run in PHP 7.

The requirement is that the new blog have an URL of `foo.example`, and the legacy would be in `foo.example/bar`.

Due to different PHP versions, each one is hosted in a different machine. Until now, the closest I got was having a subdomain `bar.foo.example` pointing to the legacy blog, but couldn't make `foo.example/bar` do the same thing (don't even know if it's possible).

I would gladly apreciate some help with this task and I'm open to new alternatives.

Comment: You need to understand that the DNS resolution operates only on the hostname and not the path, so `foo.example` and `foo.example/bar` will arrive to the same host. There, the host could be configured to redirect or proxy one of the path to another host.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server's software, I know you can do something like in NGINX:

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld;
    root /var/www/wordpress;

    index index.php;

    ...

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /bar/ {
            root /var/www/wordpress-legacy;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not really point to different server based on request path - domain will always point to one server (at least from user perspective). However this one server could work as a proxy and serve content from correct server. Potential solutions:

1. Put a load balancer in front of this two servers - see [HAProxy - URL Based routing with load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606544/haproxy-url-based-routing-with-load-balancing).
2. Configure new server as a proxy to serve content from legacy server for subdirectory. For example by using [NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/):

   ```
   location /bar/ {
       proxy_pass http://legacy.foo.example/bar/;
   }
   ```